# Jump Game - Leetcode

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

Below is my solution for the [LeetCode Jump Game](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/)

> Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned
> at the first index of the array.
>
> Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that
> position.
>
> Determine if you are able to reach the last index.

Example 1:

> Input: [2,3,1,1,4]
>
> Output: true

This is my solution. It is correct but timed out the LeetCode code-checker for an array of 25000 elements.

Please can someone help me improve this code.

It seems to have a time complexity of `O(N^2)` and a space complexity of O(N). I cannot work out a method faster than `O(N^2)`.

```
def function(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return True
    output = [0] * len(nums)
    last_index = len(nums) - 1
    output[0] = 1

    for index, number in enumerate(nums):
        if output[index] == 0:
            continue
        if output[index] == 1:
            stop_at = min(last_index, index + number)
            for i in range(index, stop_at + 1):
                output[i] = 1
        if output[last_index] == 1:
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [3,2,1,0,4]
    output = function(nums)
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### O(n) Solution

You don't need to keep track of all the places you can reach.  You only need to know what is the highest index you can reach, because you can reach any lower index by choosing a shorter jump.  Scan the list from 0 to the end keeping track of the maximum reachable index.  If you ever reach an index greater than the maximum reachable index, you've hit a block and can't reach the end.

For example, for a jump list = [3,2,1,0,4].  Starting at index 0, we can reach any index up to 0 + 3 = 3.  From index 1 we can reach 1 + 2 = 3.  From 2, we can reach 2+1 = 3.  From index 3, we can reach 3 + 0 = 3.  So far the maximum reachable index is 3.  So when we reach index 4, 4 > 3 so index 4 is unreachable and we can't get to the end.

```
def canjump(nums):
    maximum_reachable_index = 0

    for index, max_jump in enumerate(nums):
        #print(f"{index}", end=' ')
        if index > maximum_reachable_index:
            #print(f"> {maximum_reachable_index} and is unreachable.")
            return False

        #print(f"+ {max_jump} => {index + max_jump} : {maximum_reachable_index} ")
        maximum_reachable_index = max(index + max_jump, maximum_reachable_index)

    return True
```

Uncomment the print statements to see how it works.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested as “Performance improvements” :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Coding style

Your code passes the [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com) check without errors or warnings, that's great.

#### Naming

The function name `function` is pretty non-descriptive. The Leetcode template uses `canJump`, but according to Python [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

that would be `can_jump`. Your `output` array stores which positions are reachable from the initial position, a better name might be `reachable`. The `index` is the current *position,* and `number` is the *jump width* at that position.

#### Coding improvements

The `output`/`reachable` array should be an array of *boolean* values instead of integers. The test

```
if output[index] == 0:
    continue
```

is not needed, and the test

```
if output[last_index] == 1:
    return True
```

needs only to be done at reachable positions. Summarizing the suggestions so far, we have

```
def can_jump(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return True
    reachable = [False] * len(nums)
    last_pos = len(nums) - 1
    reachable[0] = True

    for pos, jump_width in enumerate(nums):
        if reachable[pos]:
            stop_at = min(last_pos, pos + jump_width)
            for i in range(pos, stop_at + 1):
                reachable[i] = True
            if reachable[last_pos]:
                return True
    return False
```

#### Performance improvements

The crucial observation is that the list of reachable positions is always an *interval* (from position `0` to some maximal reachable position). This interval can be described by a single integer variable

```
last_reachable = 0
```

which is updated while traversing the array. I won't deprive you of the satisfaction to program the solution yourself, therefore I'll mention only the general idea. While enumerating the array:

- If the current position is not reachable then return `False`.
- Otherwise, update `last_reachable` with the maximum of its current value and the greatest position reachable from the current position.
- Return `True` as soon as the final position turns out to be reachable.

This approach needs less memory (no additional array), and only a simple loop instead of nested loops.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, this is the method I figured would be much faster. Sorry for deleting it before and thank you for your reply.